# Slide indicator with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I really need your helps regarding to the code I did recently.

In my code, I tried to copy picture of the data table and paste it to slide 5 of Powerpoint. There are about 20 worksheets like this so I combined all into 1 code (ran successfully), but all have same problem.
What I want is the copied picture is paste at where the text box with number 5 is in, but somehow when I copy it, the text box appears there (it happens to all other slides as well). The picture indicated below.
Does anyone know where I did wrongly? I really appreciate for the helps

```
Sub Copy_Picture2()
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ActiveSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPApp.Visible = msoCTrue
PPApp.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Users\huhiuhi\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\Monthly report - final table picture.pptx"

Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
Set ActiveSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

     Workbooks("Monthly report data.xlsm").Activate
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TCH - Slide 1").Range("B4:K18").CopyPicture
     With PPPres.Slides(5)
     .Select
     .Shapes.Paste
     .Shapes(1).Select
      PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
      PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
      PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = 15.5
      PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = 62.5
        With ActiveSlide.Shapes(ActiveSlide.Shapes.Count)
          .Width = 932
          If .Width > 932 Then .Width = 932
        End With
     End With
End Sub
```

What I have now:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Just to clarify, you want your picture to be pasted in **Textbox 5**? From what i can see with your current code, you are just asking to copy the picture in `Slide 5`